# PyCharm does not display Cyrillic

Tags: json, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, pycharm

Help fix the problem:
The task was the following - to save the database model in the fixed structure. I did it using the terminal (python manage.py dumpdata ...)
Json file was created but does not display Cyrillic. utf-8 encoding, please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kCaf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kdWZ.png)

I tried to change the encoding type in the settings, I tried to manually rewrite the json file

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example deduced from your picture): `'╬фхцфр ═ютшэъш'.encode( 'cp866').decode( 'cp1251')` returns `Одежда Новинки`. Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve]. Where possible, copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json


file = 
r'C:\Programming\python_django\store\products\fixtures\category.json'
file_2 = 
r'C:\Programming\python_django\store\products\fixtures\category.json'

with open(file, 'rb') as open_file:
    data = json.load(open_file)
    with open(file_2, 'w') as write_file:
        write_file.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False,
                                    indent=0,

                                    separators=(',',  ': 
                                   ')).encode('cp866').decode('cp1251'))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).